# Angularjs: How can I run my custom directive after template compiled

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I writing custom directive and I want my directive to access a child element by generated id as in the code below

```
<div class="my-directive" data-rawdata="user-{{user_id}}">
    <div class="raw user-{{user_id}}" id="user-{{user_id}}" style='display:none'>
        I'M HERE.
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my directive:

```
.directive('myDirective', [function(Cart) {

  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    priority: -1000,
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        var element_id = attrs.rawdata

        if(element_id){

            var found1 = angular.element("#" + element_id); // not found
            var found2 = angular.element("." + element_id); // not found
            var found3 = angular.element(".raw"); // found

            console.log( [found1.length, found2.length, found3.length] );
            console.log( found3.attr('id') );       //  -> still not compile = user-{{user_id}} ?
            console.log( found3.attr('class') );    //  -> still not compile = user-{{user_id}} ?
        }

    }
  };
}])
```

And my directive cannot access to the element by id because it's not finish binding value of id yet.

Is there a way to let my directive execute after binding finish? I tried priority -1000 with no luck.

my plunker is : http://plnkr.co/edit/2J7t6qK7F5MtyWI64Wpa?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your directive work in `$timeout`. This allows the link code to run after rendering is completed, eg:

```
$timeout(function(){
    if(element_id){
        var found1 = angular.element("#" + element_id)
        var found2 = angular.element("." + element_id)
        var found3 = angular.element(".raw")

        console.log( [found1.length, found2.length, found3.length] );
        console.log( found3.attr('id') );       //  -> still not compile = user-{{user_id}} ?
        console.log( found3.attr('class') );    //  -> still not compile = user-{{user_id}} ?

        if(found1.length)
            data = "Your data is " + found1.html()
        }

        angular.element(".result", elem).html( data || "Data not found" )
 }, 0);
```

Also don't forget to inject `$timeout` into your directive.

Comment: Ahh, you're right. How do I forgot that $timeout can fix almost everything. thanks, Matt.